# Using EventSource with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server-sent-events

I am trying to work out how EventSource might help solve an update problem with a web applications.

I would like to be able to notify visitors to a web page when one or another visitor has performed an update. The idea is:

- One visitor makes some changes to a text area and submits.
- The data is submitted using Ajax.
- At the server, the changes are saved.
- *I would like the server to send a notification that changes have been made*
- *I would like all other visitors to get this notification*.

On the server in PHP, I have something like this:

```php
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    //  process changes

    $data = sprintf('data: {"time": "%s","type": "save"}',$date);

    header("Cache-Control: no-store");
    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
    print "event: ping\n$data\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    exit;
}
```

In JavaScript I have something like this:

```js
var eventSource = new EventSource("https://example.net/ajax.php", { withCredentials: true } );
eventSource.addEventListener("ping", (event) => {
    const time = JSON.parse(event.data).time;
    const type = JSON.parse(event.data).type;
    console.log(`Ping at ${time} for ${type}`);
});
```

That doesn’t do the job at all. At the client end I get get an error message about the wrong headers (I think that it’s because there’s no `save` yet, so the PHP falls through to an empty string).

All the samples I have seen include a `while(true)` loop in the PHP, but non have a one-off event.

Is this possible to implement, and, if so, how?

Comment: The event stream needs to be constantly open, otherwise the browser will lose connection with it. So probably the architecture needs to be something along the lines of: AJAX call is sent, and PHP code writes data about the event to a database, queue, or some other suitable (semi-)persistent storage. Meanwhile, another PHP script is in charge of providing the event stream, and is constantly looping. It checks the database/queue/whatever for new data frequently, and then issues a new server-sent-event whenever it sees something new.

Comment: P.S. Another approach to this scenario could be to use a websocket server. Since that enables bi-directional communication between browser and server, it could replace both the AJAX and the Server-sent events.

Comment: for such usecase you can search for any signalr js library based on websocket. then create hub instance which transfers the massage or notification from client to the server and vice versa